# error: package com.facebook.yoga does not exist

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

i install react-native-svg when compiling i got this error

```
 error: package com.facebook.yoga does not exist
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Always remember to Google first: a search for the error message and "react-native-svg" points to a Github issue that offers a fix. Luckily, usually someone else has already had the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

Do:

`npm install react-native-svg@4.4.1`

then you may need to do:

`cd android; gradlew clean`

Taken from: https://github.com/capitalone/react-native-pathjs-charts/issues/55